# I need to use the vector class in my main and in my header cpp file .... What's the proper protocol?

Tags: c++

Sorry. I'm somewhat new to building larger programs and linking files together and all that good stuff.

My function declarations in my header .h file have std::vector in them. Those function implementations in my header .cpp file also use std::vector. From my understanding, I should just use the "#include " in my header .h file because everything from that file will essentially be pasted into my header .cpp file at compile time. I'm just trying to make sure.

My .cpp file:

```
#include "PlagiarismDetector_Header.h"

// implementations of functions defined in PlagiarismDetector_Header.h
```

PlagiarismDetector_Header.h:

```
#include <iostream> // std::cout, std::endl
#include <vector>  // std::vector
#include <string> // std::string
#include <algorithm> // std::swap
#include <math.h> // sqrt()
#include <set> // std::set
#include <map> // std::map
#include <fstream> // std::ifstream

std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > get_file_sntncs(std::fstream&);
std::vector<std::string> get_sntnc_wrds(const std::string&);
double sntnc_smlrty_qtnt(std::vector<std::string>, std::vector<std::string>);

// All the characters that constitute a word 
const char LETTERS_ARR[] = {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'."};
const std::set<char> LETTERS_SET(LETTERS_ARR, LETTERS_ARR +    sizeof(LETTERS_ARR)/sizeof(char));
```

Comment: Either way is fine. Just be consistent.

Comment: Not the question you asked but I wouldn't define `LETTERS_SET` like that. Although it's correct, by defining it in the header file, every file you include PlagiarismDetector_Header.h in will get a separate copy of `LETTERS_SET`, each of which is going to have to be expensively constructed. Just put `extern const std::set<char> LETTERS_SET;` in your header file and move the definition to one of your cpp files. You should probably do the same with `LETTERS_ARR` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You got it pretty much right but consider these aspects:

- try to put an [include guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in your header file since you may need to have it included twice in row in a future file
- consider to push down to the implementation file(s) all constants and functions declarations that do not need to be exposed to the extern modules (whichever file including your header will see them even tough it does not need to use them)
- if you use those constants  in other files (that will include your header), follow john suggestion and make them `extern`